# "Don't Keep Activities" is set, onSaveInstanceState not called

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, onsaveinstancestate

I'm testing that my app is able to recover from unexpected situations that lead the OS to kill my app's process due to different circumstances like low memory. To do this, I've enabled "Don't Keep Activities" in Developer Options.

I'm attempting to restore the app's state by saving state values in the Activity's Bundle through the lifecycle method `onSaveInstanceState`, but after setting breakpoints I've noticed that `onSaveInstanceState` **does not get called**.

**Question**:
Am I wrong in expecting `onSaveInstanceState` to be called in this scenario or might there be other factors that are preventing the method to fire? If neither, what else can I do to recover the state in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I think two possibilities are supposed.

1. Your scenario is wrong

[The official reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) says:

> Do not confuse this method with activity lifecycle callbacks such as
>   onPause(), which is always called when the user no longer actively
>   interacts with an activity, or onStop() which is called when activity
>   becomes invisible. One example of when onPause() and onStop() is
>   called and not this method is when a user navigates back from activity
>   B to activity A: there is no need to call onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)
>   on B because that particular instance will never be restored, so the
>   system avoids calling it. An example when onPause() is called and not
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is when activity B is launched in front of
>   activity A: the system may avoid calling onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)
>   on activity A if it isn't killed during the lifetime of B since the
>   state of the user interface of A will stay intact.

If your scenario is a 'no need to call' case, `onSaveInstanceState` won't be called.

2. Your breakpoints are wrong

> If called, this method will occur after onStop() for applications
>   targeting platforms starting with Build.VERSION_CODES.P. For
>   applications targeting earlier platform versions this method will
>   occur before onStop() and there are no guarantees about whether it
>   will occur before or after onPause().

So the timing of `onSaveInstanceState` called depends on your targeting platform.

An easy workaround is to backup data with SharedPreference, etc. in onPause.